# What is an effective way to load data to test mobile app upgrades

Tags: android, ios, mobile, uwp, regression-testing

We have a mobile app on iOS, Android, and UWP. Each release, we use the platform specific way to host a beta version. Then we install the production release of the app from the app store, add some basic data, and then install the beta version over the top to test version to version upgrades. However, this is not a sufficient test as the data is very simple vs testing a db upgrade for a user who has had the app for years with lots of data. It also doesn't cover v1.1 to v1.5, v1.2 to v1.5, etc tests. We can do those tests as well, but the loading of a good set of data is very time consuming.

What is a good way on each platform to load a very large simulated data set? As far as I can tell, I have no ability to replace the SQLite db on iOS or Android. How do people do this type of testing? Do you add the ability to pull the simulated data from your server and load it into the db? Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are not that many options to regression testing, you could try `Appium` to install/run multiple binaries and run your test scenarios to see if app behaviour is as expected.

checkout :

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/